# Images streamed over tcp are split in 3 with middle missing

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tcp, raspberry-pi

[image: Example of result]

The goal of the project is to stream video captured from a python host to a c# client via tcp sockets.

Relavent python2 server script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
from threading import Thread

_continue = True
def imageStreamer4():
    global _continue
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    camSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    camSocket.bind(("",8081))
    camSocket.listen(1)
    # set flip image to false if you don't want the image to be flipped
    flipImage = True

    while _continue:
        try:
            client,address = camSocket.accept()
            print("client connected")
            ret,camImage = cam.read()
            if flipImage:
                camImage = cv2.flip(camImage,1)

            #uncomment the below code to view the webcam stream locally
            """
            cv2.imshow('image',camImage)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
                break  # esc to quit
            """
            byteString = bytes(cv2.imencode('.jpg', camImage)[1].tostring())
            fileSize = len(byteString)
            totalSent = 0
            client.send(str(fileSize).encode())

            sizeConfirmation = client.recv(1024)

            totalSent = 0
            while totalSent < fileSize:
                totalSent += client.send(byteString[totalSent:])

            print(str(fileSize), str(totalSent),sizeConfirmation.decode('utf-8'))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("shutting down video stream")
            _continue = False

    print("video stream exited.")
```

Relevant c# client code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

void getVideoStream()
    {
        byte[] header; 
        int recieved;
        int fileSize;
        NetworkStream dataStream;
        MemoryStream ms;
        while (connectCam)
        {
            fileSize = 0;
            recieved = 0;
            camClient = new TcpClient(camIP, camPort);

            //get header
            dataStream = camClient.GetStream();
            while (!dataStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                //waste time
            }
            header = new byte[1024];
            dataStream.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
            fileSize = Int32.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesReducer(header)));
            byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileSize.ToString());

            //send response
            dataStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);

            ms = new MemoryStream();
            while (!dataStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                //waste time
            }
            while (recieved < fileSize)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[camClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                recieved += dataStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
            //the below class simply sends function calls from secondary thread back to the main thread
            UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(convertBytesToTexture(ms.ToArray()));
            dataStream.Close();
            camClient.Close();

        }
    }

void convertBytesToTexture(byte[] byteArray) {
        try
        {
            camTexture.LoadImage(byteArray); //Texture2D object
            camImage.texture = camTexture; //RawImage object
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print(e);
        }
    }
```

The byte counts sent and received match as they should. I'm admittedly new to working with sockets but I'm pretty certain that the data is arriving whole and intact. Unfortunately I really have no idea why the image is splitting as it is. (As shown in the above image) If it's relevant at all, both the server and client functions are being run on their own separate threads.

I've run the scripts on separate hosts and clients and the results remain the same.If any different information is required to help, just ask. I'll be happy to update as required.

Comment: Is your data length fixed?

Comment: The data length is quite variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to bring the picture together properly by removing empty space inserted by the following code:

```
while (recieved < fileSize)
{
     byte[] data = new byte[camClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
     recieved += dataStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
     ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

}
```

replacing it with this:

```
int increment = 0;
while (recieved < fileSize)
{
     byte[] data = new byte[camClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
     increment = dataStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
     recieved += increment; 
     ms.Write(data.Take(increment).ToArray(), 0, increment);

}
```

So instead of taking an array the size of the client's buffer into the memory stream(even if it wasn't full), it's being condensed to only the amount of information received via the read method. This effectively removed all the blank space in the received image.

Answer (score 0):

Because Tcp is a stream you should consider it as a flow of bytes so you should apply some mechanism to identify each image
this way you can apply:

- **A delimiter**:
  use a set of bytes to separate each image( but this byte set must not repeated in your stream) for example:

> 1- send image bytes
>
> 2-send delimiter

in the client you start to read until reach the delimiter

- Consider defining a **protocol** and send the image size first and then send image data for example :

> 1-first 8 bytes is always image size
>
> 2- then the image bytes

and when you read data on the client first you always read 8 bytes and then base on this size you read the rest of data.

- Another way is to use fixed size data(which is a bit hard for you in this case) you get a fix size byte array in the server and if the image data is less than the byte array fill it with zero and on the client always read bytes as many as the server array size.

> Server Send byte[2048] and Client reads until the bytes which is readed reach 2048

Comment: Using 8 bytes (a `long`) to indicate the image size is quite wasteful. 4 bytes (an `int` or `uint`) should be more than enough since I doubt any image will be larger than 2 or 4 GB (`int.MaxValue` or `uint.MaxValue`).